# How scrape element that doesn't belong to any attribute in a class

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This issue happens to the same page that I asked yesterday. The url is:
https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor

I am trying to scrape the date of the match: 
I want to get:

Waldstadion Frankfurt, Saturday, May 20, 2017 - 14:30

Then, extract:

May 20, 2017

[image]

And this happens to be in side here from the inspect element view:
[image]

I try to access to this div tag and teams class in the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

url = "https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
# Try find date
date = soup.select('div.teams')
date_raw = date[0].text
date_strip = date_raw.strip()
y = re.findall('(^[A-Z].+)\n', date_strip)
y1 = str(y).strip()
print(y1)
```

But this is not quite successful...the result is still somehow in a list and with lots of space to be trimmed. The problem is that there are lots of children of this class, and I just wanted to access the class='teams' text element and extract the date.

```
['Waldstadion Frankfurt, Saturday, May 20, 2017 - 14:30      ']
```

Is there any better way to extract this element? Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the desired text is first content after `<div class="teams">`. You can access it in BeautifulSoup with `.contents` property, which can be indexed (0 in case of first content):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('div.teams').contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
Waldstadion Frankfurt, Saturday, May 20, 2017 - 14:30
```

EDIT:

To parse the string for place, date, time you can use regular expression:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

data = soup.select_one('div.teams').contents[0].strip()

place, date, time = re.search(r'(.*?)(?:,.*?)((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Dec)\s+\d+,\s+\d+).*?(\d+:\d+)', data).groups()
print(place)
print(date)
print(time)
```

This will print:

```
Waldstadion Frankfurt
May 20, 2017
14:30
```

Explanation of this regular expression is [here](https://regex101.com/r/lPmYbs/1).

Comment: Andrej you rock! By the way, I studied beautifulsoup, and extracted the x1, x2, y1, y2 in my own way, though your codes helped me a lot in understanding the nature of the structure!

Comment: @commentallez-vous I updated my answer to see how to parse the string for desired values (like place, date, time)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain JS before parsing it.

```
document.getElementById("match-head").
    children[0].
    innerText. 
    split(/[,-]/).
    splice(1,2).
    join("")

// produces " Saturday May 20"
```

The first three statements are just W3C DOM; the last 3 are array manipulation to extract the second and third items separated by "-" or "," characters and join them back together.

Comment: So further use/apply this in other situations, I have to learn JavaScript right?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain what it's doing. You should be able to do this in python no problems.

Comment: The BeautifulSoup library lets you use CSS selectors with `soup.select`; there are a million CSS tutorial sites. Any python tutorial will cover arrays. You can use codecademy.com for both.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it!

Comment: when I run it in my python spyder, why do I get a invalid syntax error at the split() method?

Comment: Ah, python's `split()` method doesn't seem to take a regular expression as a parameter. Try `re.compile("[,-]").split("My, string - to, split")`

Answer (score 1):

My first choice, `dateutil.parser` wasn't able to find the date, so I used a simple regex to extract it. The only caveat is that the date must begin with the full month name and end with a dash or newline.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

pattern = "(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)[^-\n.]+"
print(re.search(pattern, soup.select("div.teams")[0].text).group().strip())
```

Output:

```
May 20, 2017
```

Personally, I trust that the site will be more consistent about date format than, say, commas or whitespace, but here's a version like that:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/22-2016/matches/861695/team-stats/6339/0_SHOT_01#tabs-wrapper-anchor"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

print(" ".join(re.split("\s+", soup.select("div.teams")[0].text)[4:7]))
```

Comment: Awesome...well by now I already extracted the date by using the methods above combined with regex, but still, this is a great way to do so. The site is quite consistent with the dates, so definitely, it works to extract different dates on different pages using your solution. Thanks a lot!